# File from $_POST and Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

i have problem with amazon s3 service and a web service writed with php.
This WS receive from $_POST a file base64encoded. I need to take this "string" and save to Amazon S3 bucket.
I didn't find a right solution for do that, and after a week of work I'm looking for help here.

```
//$file = 'kdK9IWUAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd'
$file = $_POST['some_file'];
$opt = array(
      'fileUpload' => base64_decode($file),
      'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
    );
$s3 = new AmazonS3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $filename, $opt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/a51029f01aa348ed7421eb211d2441becbc9a494/services/s3.class.php#L1308), `fileUpload` expects a URL or path, or an `fopen` resource.

> `fileUpload` - `string|resource` - Required; Conditional - The URL/path for the file to upload, or an open resource. Either this parameter or `body` is required.

You should pass the decoded file data via the `body` parameter instead:

> `body` - `string` - Required; Conditional - The data to be stored in the object. Either this parameter or `fileUpload` must be specified.

Comment: Thanks! But i need anymore..
Now i store the file (sometimes it's an image), but if i open it on browser it say to me that the file is corrupted.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The imagestring is the base64 encoded string that was passed from POST data. You can encode this image and make a file to anywhere - in my case /photos. I used this is a school server, but if Amazon server is similar enough, it could also work there.

```
    $values = array();
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        $values[$k] = $v;
    }
    $imagestring = $values['stringEncodedImage'];

    $img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($imagestring));
        if($img != false)
        {
            echo 'making the file!';
            imagejpeg($img, 'photos/'.$file_name);
        }
```